# Replay Button for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a replay button for my setTimeout Function

So that when i click the replay button, It will replay the transitions while not reloading the current page

I prefer javascript only

Comment: Please provide the piece of code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
var timeout;

function yourTimeoutFunction() {
    timeout = setTimeout( /* put your code here */ );
}
    
function replayTimeoutFunction() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);  // clear timeout
    yourTimeoutFunction();  // restart timeout
}
```

Let it run replayTimeoutFunction when you press your button.